# How to use same function for different Id's in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```js
function add() {
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("book");
  var newNumber = parseInt(book.value) + 1;
  book.value = newNumber;
}

function sub() {
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById("book");
  var newNumber = parseInt(book.value) - 1;
  book.value = newNumber;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <label>Book</label>
  <a href="#" onClick="sub()">subtract</a><input type="text" id="book" value="0" min="0"><a href="#" onClick="add()"> Add</a>
</div>

<div class="range">
  <label>Pen</label>
  <a href="#" onClick="sub()">subtract</a><input type="text" id="pen" value="0" min="0"><a href="#" onClick="add()"> Add</a>
</div>
```

How to use same function for different Id's?

I tried using "this" keyword for selecting a current Id but it didn't work...
and i am trying do this in javascript only instead of jquery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the id as parameter for calling the functions. Inside take the value and convert it to number and if falsey, like `NaN` take a zero as value.

```js
function add(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id),
        value = +element.value || 0;

    element.value = value + 1;
}

function sub(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id),
        value = +element.value || 0;

    value--;
    if (value < 0) {
        value = 0;
    }
    element.value = value;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <label>Book</label>
  <a href="#" onClick="sub('book')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true">-</i></a><input type="text" id="book" value="0" min="0">
  <a href="#" onClick="add('book')"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true">+</i></a>
</div>

<div class="range">
  <label>Pen</label>
  <a href="#" onClick="sub('pen')"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle" aria-hidden="true">-</i></a><input type="text" id="pen" value="0" min="0">
  <a href="#" onClick="add('pen')"> <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true">+</i></a>
</div>
```

Input free version with an object as storage.

```js
function add(id) {
    storage[id] = storage[id] || 0;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = ++storage[id];
}

function sub(id) {
    storage[id] = storage[id] || 0;
    --storage[id];
    if (storage[id] < 0) {
        storage[id] = 0;
    }
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = storage[id];
}

var storage = {};
```

```html
<label>Book</label> <a href="#" onClick="sub('book')">-</a> <span id="book">0</span> <a href="#" onClick="add('book')">+</a><br>
<label>Pen</label> <a href="#" onClick="sub('pen')">-</a> <span id="pen">0</span> <a href="#" onClick="add('pen')">+</i></a>
```

Comment: element.value = +element.value + 1;Please explain this line. Thank You

Comment: no, because if the user enters some text, then it does not work and retuns `NaN`.

Comment: the plus is an unary plus which converts a string to a number, if possible or to `NaN`, not a number.

Comment: one more question. instead of using input tag can i use a div tag so that a user can't input a string. and how to do that?

Comment: in this case, i would store the value in an object with the same name of id as key and maintain the value in the object. Then instead of `.value` use `.innerHTML` for assignment.

Answer (score 1):

pass `id name` in `function like add('book') or add('pen')` and this use in function call in javascript

and also use `txtNumber` instead of `book` in `java script`

```js
function add(id) {
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(id);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) + 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}

function sub(id) {
  var txtNumber = document.getElementById(id);
  var newNumber = parseInt(txtNumber.value) - 1;
  txtNumber.value = newNumber;
}
```

```html
<div class="range">
  <label>Book</label>
  <a href="#" onClick="sub('book')">subtract</a><input type="text" id="book" value="0" min="0"><a href="#" onClick="add('book')"> Add</a>
</div>

<div class="range">
  <label>Pen</label>
  <a href="#" onClick="sub('pen')">subtract</a><input type="text" id="pen" value="0" min="0"><a href="#" onClick="add('pen')"> Add</a>
</div>
```